# how to use unique height and width in html and display any image perfectly on webpage

Tags: html

I am working on a Web application project. I successfully created a web app for a specific client with their own logo. Now i need to use the same code and display another logo (having different height and width compared to previous client logo) for giving it them. I can just align this logo by changing height and width attributes of previous clientcode. But i don't want that to be done.

Here it is:

```
<img src="firstclientlogo.png" height="70" width="250">
```

But when i use same attributes for second logo image is stretched and ugly.

```
<img src="secondclientlogo.png" height="75" width="250">
```

i tried scaling the second logo to different sizes but whatever size i scale the image seems to be stretched.

Please help me. Here is the logo details:

firstclientlogo: 1694 width x 547 height.
secondclientlogo: 423 width x 246 height.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css:

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-width:250px;
  max-height:75px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```